# Combining plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Hi im new to python here.

I am trying to plot a line and a circle on the same graph to see if they intersect based on the user's input. This is what I have currently. I am not very familiar with matplotlib and after socuring through the internet for hours I am unable to combine the graphs properly. Can anyone help me.
Thanks a lot

Code and plot

[image: 1]

I tried using the extend function as well as combine but to no avail

Comment: Check this [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Don't create a new figure for the circle. Add it to the same axes as the line.

Comment: `after socuring through the internet for hours` - the Matplolib documentation is very good with many examples and a [Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html). Spend some time with their tutorial, then look through the [example gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To plot several items in one graph, you can simply do:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show
```

Both curve will appear on the same figure.
Also, please put code rather than image so it's easier to replicate.